# Checking for items in a MiniZinc array

Tags: minizinc

I want to create two arrays in MiniZinc with the same items, not necessarily in the same order. Here, every item in `A0` should also be in `A1`:

```
array[1..3] of var int:A0;
array[1..3] of var int:A1;

constraint forall(A2 in A0)(
  (A2 in A1) /\ A2 < 5
 );
```

But here, there seems to be a type error:

```
MiniZinc: type error: type error in operator application for `'in''. No matching operator found with left-hand side type `var int' and right-hand side type `array[int] of var int'
```

How is it possible to check if an array contains the same item that is in another array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: There is an `array2set` in the file `builtins.mzn` but it is not documented in https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.2/ .

The following model works for most FlatZinc solvers such as Gecode, Google-OR-tools, Choco, PicatSAT, and JaCoP, but not for Chuffed (see below). Note the include of "nosets.mzn" so that solvers without innate support for set variables can run the model. Also, I added a smaller domain of `A0` and `A1` for easier testing.

```
include "nosets.mzn"; % Support for set variables for all solvers
array[1..3] of var 0..10: A0;
array[1..3] of var 0..10: A1;

constraint
   forall(A2 in A0)( 
     A2 in array2set(A1) /\ A2 < 5
   )
   /\
   forall(A2 in A1)(
     A2 in array2set(A0) /\ A2 < 5
   );

   solve satisfy;

   output [ "A0: \(A0) A1: \(A1)\n" ];
```

However, some solvers don't like this:

- Chuffed: Throws "Error: Registry: Constraint bool_lin_eq not found in line no. 101"

**Even later note**: If the domains is `var int` (instead of my `var 0..10`) then MiniZinc croaks with a weird (and long) error:

```
...
in array comprehension expression
  comprehension iterates over an infinite set
```

So `array2set` seems to require that the variable domains must be bounded.

**This is the first answer**
Here is an approach that seems to work, i.e. using `exists` and check for element equality:

```
constraint forall(A2 in A0)(
              exists(i in 1..3) ( A2 = A1[i] /\ A2 < 5)
);
```

Note: This constraint only ensures that the elements in A0 is in A1.  Thus there might be elements in A1 that is not in A0. E.g.

A0: [1,1,4]

A1: [1,4,3]

I guess that you also want the converse i.e. that all elements in A1 is in A0 as well:

```
constraint forall(A2 in A1) (
   exists(i in 1..3) ( A2 = A0[i] /\ A2 < 5)
);
```

Note: The following **DOES NOT** work but would be nice to have. Both yield the error `MiniZinc: internal error: var set comprehensions not supported yet`.

```
% idea 1
constraint forall(A2 in A0)(
   A2 in {A1[i] | i in 1..3} /\ A2 < 5
);

% idea 2
constraint forall(A2 in A0) (
     A2 in {a | a in A1} /\ A2 < 5         
);
```

Comment: An array2set function apparently does exist, but it [produces a runtime error](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/370) when I try to use it.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  `array2set` is not documented but is in the builtins.mzn. I have updated my answer.  Note the use of `import "nosets.mzn` to support sets for all solvers; though Chuffed still yield an error.

Comment: I noted that `array2set` don't work with `var int` and updated the answer. I added a comment about this on the GitHub issue.